# How to define two dimensional array in fortran

Tags: fortran

I have catalog which I need to categorize its values in an array :
with this code

```
       ii=1      
 101   read(20,*,end=102)ra(ii),dec(ii),mag_g(ii),mag_r(ii),mag_i(ii),redshift(ii)   
       do i=1,n
          z(i)=zmin+(i-1)*step   
          zup(i)=z(i)+step
          do j=1,b      !mag loop
             mag(j)=mag_min+(j-1)*bin
             magup(j)=mag(j)+bin
             if (z(i) >= redshift(ii).and.redshift(ii) <= zup(i).and.mag(j) >= mag_i(ii).and.mag_i(ii) <= magup(j) ) then
                array(i,j)=mag_i(ii)
                write(4,'(2x,3f10.5,2x,4f10.5)')z(i),zup(i),redshift(ii),mag(j),magup(j),mag_i(ii),array(i,j)
             else 
                goto 103
             end if
          end do 
       end do   
 103   ii=ii+1  
       goto 101   
 102   total=ii-1
```

While I'm running this code, it overwrites all the values in each dimension.
How can define a two dimensional array with the rank of s, (all the objects fits in the if condition).

thanks

Comment: What is `s`? Note that `array` is already defined as a 2D array (it has indices `i` and `j`). Note also that `goto` is an abhorrent statement and should be avoided at all costs, use a `do` loop instead!

Comment: some issues - This is not fortran77. (illegal comments, illegal logical operators) your lines are way too long for fixed form fortran.  If its being compiled as freeform that makes the use of statement numbers doubly icky.

Comment: I need an array which I can put different values in each dimension for example at the A(1,1) I should have many values like as 100

Comment: This would mean, you need a *three*-dimensional array... Just add this index in the declaration part of your source file and add the appropriate index in your calls. E.g. `A(1,1,2)` for the second element at `(1,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

like Stefan said - you would need a 3D array. I see a couple of possible issues with your code:

- Lines to long (I'm not sure gfortran would compile this with the default settings)
- Gotos instead of loops
- Unclear boundaries / dimensions
- Not every element might be set
- Order of the dimensions (Fortran is column major)

I would suggest something of the following if the number of elements (index `ii`) is known a priori:

```
! Allocate array
allocate( array( n, b, nElements ), stat=ierr )
if ( ierr .ne. 0 ) stop 'Cannot allocate memory!'
! Initialize array
array = 0

! Main loop
do ii=1,nElements
  read(20,*,iostat=ierr)ra(ii),dec(ii),mag_g(ii),mag_r(ii),mag_i(ii),redshift(ii)
  if ( ierr .ne. 0 ) stop 'Cannot read from unit 20!'

  ! Original loop 
  do i=1,n
    z(i)=zmin+(i-1)*step   
    zup(i)=z(i)+step
    do j=1,b      !mag loop
      mag(j)=mag_min+(j-1)*bin
      magup(j)=mag(j)+bin
      if (z(i) >= redshift(ii) .and.&
          redshift(ii) <= zup(i).and. &
          mag(j) >= mag_i(ii).and. &
          mag_i(ii) <= magup(j) ) then
        ! Write value
        array(i,j,ii)=mag_i(ii)
        write(4,'(2x,3f10.5,2x,4f10.5)') z(i),zup(i),redshift(ii), &
          mag(j),magup(j),mag_i(ii),array(i,j,ii)
      end if
    end do ! j
   end do ! i    
enddo ! ii

! [...]
! Clean up
if ( allocated(array) ) deallocate(array)
```

Of course, this is Fortran 90/95 so you would need to convert this to Fortran 77 if necessary.

If the number of elements is **not** known, you could either use chained lists (which might be oversized depending on the problem), or define an upper limit and use the code above. Then, you need to change the `stop` statement within the loop to an `exit` statement and store the actual number of elements.

If you are dealing with large arrays I would strongly suggest to change the order of the dimensions:

```
! Allocate array
allocate( array( b, n, nElements ), stat=ierr )
if ( ierr .ne. 0 ) stop 'Cannot allocate memory!'
! [...]
array(j,i,ii)  = mag_i(ii)
```